# So weir in script-fu, cadr function not work

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

`> (cadr '(1 2 3)) Error: eval: unbound variable: cadr`

I think who are familiar with script-fu should think as i am, this is so weir. Just few day ago, i ran some thing like "cadr" or even "caaadr" smoothly. Please help me.

i search on google 10 pages but there are not thing similarly.

Comment: Do you mean "weird"?

Comment: Do the other functions like `caar` work?

Comment: yes, of course weird :)). I've try `caar` and the result is the same. `> (caar '(1 2 3))
Error: eval: unbound variable: caar`

Comment: and i use the latest version of GIMP -> 3.10.34

Comment: Did you upgrade gimp between the last time it worked and now?

Comment: Last version is 2.10.34, not 3.10.34. `cadr` is used in 22 of the standard scripts, such as `Drop shadow (legacy)`. Do these still work? Do they work in a script but not in the script-fu console, or the script-fu console but not in a script, and don't work anywhere?

Comment: No where they work. I run `Drop shadow` and also  `cadr` on both script or script-fu console but it pop up error. In last test, i run `car` on script, it work well.

Comment: @Shawn: Yes, i've upgrade GIMP one time when it didn't include Py-fu. May be the matter appear after that. I've also uninstall gimp and reinstall with flatpak, but the problem still

Answer (score 0):

cadr, caar etc are defined in the script-fu.init file that should be in the same place as all the GIMP-supplied scripts (drop-shadow.scm, erase-lines.scm etc)

On my Windows installation this is
C:\Program Files\GIMP 2.10\share\gimp\2.0\scripts\script-fu.init